# Stop a Jquery progress bar with .click

Tags: jquery, click

You can find a copy of what I'm working on at http://jsfiddle.net/6h74c/266/

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
           $('#imgbtn').click(function () {

               var start = new Date();
               var maxTime = 10000;
               var maxTime2 = 1500;
               var timeoutVal = Math.floor(maxTime / 100);
               var timeoutVal2 = Math.floor(maxTime2 / 100);
               var maxTime3 = 650;
               var maxTime4 = 450;
               var timeoutVal3 = Math.floor(maxTime3 / 100);
               var timeoutVal4 = Math.floor(maxTime4 / 100);



               function updateProgress(percentage) {
                   $('#pbar_innerdiv').css("width", percentage + "%");
                   $('#pbar_innertext').html("<span class='biglet'>256Kb/s</span></br><span class='littlelet'>30 seconds</span>");
               };
               function updateProgress2(percentage) {
                   $('#pbar_innerdiv2').css("width", percentage + "%");
                   $('#pbar_innertext2').html("<span class='biglet'>6Mb/s</span></br><span class='littlelet'>1.25 seconds</span>");
               };

               function animateUpdate() {
                   var now = new Date();
                   var timeDiff = now.getTime() - start.getTime();
                   var perc = Math.round((timeDiff / maxTime) * 100);
                   console.log(perc);
                   if (perc <= 100) {
                       updateProgress(perc);
                       setTimeout(animateUpdate, timeoutVal);
                   }
               };

               function animateUpdate2() {
                   var now = new Date();
                   var timeDiff = now.getTime() - start.getTime();
                   var perc = Math.round((timeDiff / maxTime2) * 100);
                   console.log(perc);
                   if (perc <= 100) {
                       updateProgress2(perc);
                       setTimeout(animateUpdate2, timeoutVal2);
                   }
               };
               function updateProgress3(percentage) {
                   $('#pbar_innerdiv3').css("width", percentage + "%");
                   $('#pbar_innertext3').html("<span class='biglet'>16Mb/s</span></br><span class='littlelet'>.5 seconds</span>");
               };
               function updateProgress4(percentage) {
                   $('#pbar_innerdiv4').css("width", percentage + "%");
                   $('#pbar_innertext4').html("<span class='biglet'>20Mb/s</span></br><span class='littlelet'>.25 seconds</span>");
               };

               function animateUpdate3() {
                   var now = new Date();
                   var timeDiff = now.getTime() - start.getTime();
                   var perc = Math.round((timeDiff / maxTime3) * 100);
                   console.log(perc);
                   if (perc <= 100) {
                       updateProgress3(perc);
                       setTimeout(animateUpdate3, timeoutVal3);
                   }
               };

               function animateUpdate4() {
                   var now = new Date();
                   var timeDiff = now.getTime() - start.getTime();
                   var perc = Math.round((timeDiff / maxTime4) * 100);
                   console.log(perc);
                   if (perc <= 100) {
                       updateProgress4(perc);
                       setTimeout(animateUpdate4, timeoutVal4);
                   }
               };
               animateUpdate();
               animateUpdate2();
               animateUpdate3();
               animateUpdate4();
           });

       });





       jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
           $('#musicbtn').click(function () {

               var maxTime = 40000;
               var maxTime2 = 6000;
               var timeoutVal = Math.floor(maxTime / 100);
               var timeoutVal2 = Math.floor(maxTime2 / 100);
               var maxTime3 = 2500;
               var maxTime4 = 2000;
               var timeoutVal3 = Math.floor(maxTime3 / 100);
               var timeoutVal4 = Math.floor(maxTime4 / 100);



               function updateProgress(percentage) {

                   $('#pbar_innerdiv').css("width", percentage + "%");
                   $('#pbar_innertext').html("<span class='biglet'>256Kb/s</span></br><span class='littlelet'>2.5 minutes</span>");


               };
               function updateProgress2(percentage) {
                   $('#pbar_innerdiv2').css("width", percentage + "%");
                   $('#pbar_innertext2').html("<span class='biglet'>6Mb/s</span></br><span class='littlelet'>6 seconds</span>");
               };

               function animateUpdate() {
                    var now = new Date();
                   var timeDiff = now.getTime() - start.getTime();
                   var perc = Math.round((timeDiff / maxTime) * 100);
                   console.log(perc);
                   if (perc <= 100) {
                       updateProgress2(perc);
                       setTimeout(animateUpdate, timeoutVal);
                   }
               };

               function animateUpdate2() {
                   var now = new Date();
                   var timeDiff = now.getTime() - start.getTime();
                   var perc = Math.round((timeDiff / maxTime2) * 100);
                   console.log(perc);
                   if (perc <= 100) {
                       updateProgress2(perc);
                       setTimeout(animateUpdate2, timeoutVal2);
                   }
               };
               function updateProgress3(percentage) {
                   $('#pbar_innerdiv3').css("width", percentage + "%");
                   $('#pbar_innertext3').html("<span class='biglet'>16Mb/s</span></br><span class='littlelet'>2.5 seconds</span>");
               };
               function updateProgress4(percentage) {
                   $('#pbar_innerdiv4').css("width", percentage + "%");
                   $('#pbar_innertext4').html("<span class='biglet'>20Mb/s</span></br><span class='littlelet'>2 seconds</span>");
               };

               function animateUpdate3() {
                   var now = new Date();
                   var timeDiff = now.getTime() - start.getTime();
                   var perc = Math.round((timeDiff / maxTime3) * 100);
                   console.log(perc);
                   if (perc <= 100) {
                       updateProgress3(perc);
                       setTimeout(animateUpdate3, timeoutVal3);
                   }
               };

               function animateUpdate4() {
                   var now = new Date();
                   var timeDiff = now.getTime() - start.getTime();
                   var perc = Math.round((timeDiff / maxTime4) * 100);
                   console.log(perc);
                   if (perc <= 100) {
                       updateProgress4(perc);
                       setTimeout(animateUpdate4, timeoutVal4);
                   }
               };
               animateUpdate();
               animateUpdate2();
               animateUpdate3();
               animateUpdate4();
           });
            $(document).click(function () {       return ;});
       });









       jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
           $('#moviebtn').click(function () {

               var start = new Date();
               var maxTime = 1500000;
               var maxTime2 = 80000;
               var timeoutVal = Math.floor(maxTime / 100);
               var timeoutVal2 = Math.floor(maxTime2 / 100);
               var maxTime3 = 40000;
               var maxTime4 = 21000;
               var timeoutVal3 = Math.floor(maxTime3 / 100);
               var timeoutVal4 = Math.floor(maxTime4 / 100);



               function updateProgress(percentage) {

                   $('#pbar_innerdiv').css("width", percentage + "%");
                   $('#pbar_innertext').html("<span class='biglet'>256Kb/s</span></br><span class='littlelet'>4 hours</span>");

               };
               function updateProgress2(percentage) {
                   $('#pbar_innerdiv2').css("width", percentage + "%");
                   $('#pbar_innertext2').html("<span class='biglet'>6Mb/s</span></br><span class='littlelet'>8 minutes</span>");


               };

               function animateUpdate() {
                   var now = new Date();
                   var timeDiff = now.getTime() - start.getTime();
                   var perc = Math.round((timeDiff / maxTime) * 100);
                   console.log(perc);
                   if (perc <= 100) {
                       updateProgress(perc);
                       setTimeout(animateUpdate, timeoutVal);
                   }

               };

               function animateUpdate2() {
                   var now = new Date();
                   var timeDiff = now.getTime() - start.getTime();
                   var perc = Math.round((timeDiff / maxTime2) * 100);
                   console.log(perc);
                   if (perc <= 100) {
                       updateProgress2(perc);
                       setTimeout(animateUpdate2, timeoutVal2);
                   }
               };
               function updateProgress3(percentage) {
                   $('#pbar_innerdiv3').css("width", percentage + "%");
                   $('#pbar_innertext3').html("<span class='biglet'>16Mb/s</span></br><span class='littlelet'>5 minutes</span>");
               };
               function updateProgress4(percentage) {
                   $('#pbar_innerdiv4').css("width", percentage + "%");
                   $('#pbar_innertext4').html("<span class='biglet'>20Mb/s</span></br><span class='littlelet'>3 minutes</span>");
               };

               function animateUpdate3() {
                   var now = new Date();
                   var timeDiff = now.getTime() - start.getTime();
                   var perc = Math.round((timeDiff / maxTime3) * 100);
                   console.log(perc);
                   if (perc <= 100) {
                       updateProgress3(perc);
                       setTimeout(animateUpdate3, timeoutVal3);
                   }
               };

               function animateUpdate4() {
                   var now = new Date();
                   var timeDiff = now.getTime() - start.getTime();
                   var perc = Math.round((timeDiff / maxTime4) * 100);
                   console.log(perc);
                   if (perc <= 100) {
                       updateProgress4(perc);
                       setTimeout(animateUpdate4, timeoutVal4);
                   }
               };
               animateUpdate();
               animateUpdate2();
               animateUpdate3();
               animateUpdate4();
           });
             ;});
```

Basically what I'm trying to do is have three buttons that will cause the progress bar "pbar_innerdiv" to go from 0-100% with a designated timeout. My problem is, if I click button 1, things will go perfect, the bars will load correctly. However, if in the middle of the bars loading I click on button two, it freaks out and tries to show the css for the previous click on button one and button 2 at the same time.

My question is, is there a way to stop the javascript from the previous button after I click on button 2 then start the animation over again? Basically, kill the first iteration of the script and restart it with the timeout for button 2.

That probably made no sense, but thanks in advance for any help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

my approach consists of the following parts:

```
var progressShouldStopFlage= false;
var timer;
```

1- a flag which indicates whether the progress bar should continue or stop.

2- a timer which will hold the timer from the `setTimeOut` operation, so we can cancel it anytime we want

3-  I've also added 2 buttons as an example of what functionality could be achieved using my solution.

the stop button will stop the progress bar while the start one should start from the very beginning.

```
if (perc <= 100) {
          if(progressShouldStopFlage)
          {
              clearTimeout(timer)    
              return;
          }    
          updateProgress(perc);
```

when progressing with the values to update the bar, i'm checking if the progress should continue or not, then I cancel the progress if the stop button is clicked.

if this is what you want, then I'm glade I could help, if you still need something else, please let me know.

the full code can be found inside this updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6h74c/272/

Comment: very neat solution, only problem I find is that resume starts it over, (resets it)

Comment: Thank you for your kind words, regarding the starts it over thing, it's on purpose, as he requested for such functionality in the question :)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion! However, when I change the maxTime, that's when the issue arrises. I updated the jsfiddle to match exactly what I'm working with. If you click on btn 1, it will work fine, but if while those circles are loading I click on btn 2 or 3 (which have different timers), it starts trying to load both simultaneously. http://jsfiddle.net/6h74c/275/

Comment: I've assumed that the code provided in your question is what you were working on, now it appears that it's not.

Comment: Sorry about that, I just added more code to show what happens when it changes timeouts.